# How do I create transition arrow labels with new lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, automata

I am using the TikZ package to draw pushdown definite automata. How do I add new lines into the labels of transition arrows?

This does not work:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=3.5cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state, initial, initial where=left, accepting] (A) {A}; 
    \path[->] 
    (A) edge [loop above] node {$a, b, c$ \\ $c, d, e$ \\ foo \\ bar} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Specifically, `{$a, b, c$ \\ $c, d, e$ \\ foo \\ bar}` ignores the new lines.

Comment: You could try with the `text width` parameter of node, namely `node [text width=1cm]{...}`, although this way it is not possible to explicitly set the line breaks.

Comment: It is also possible to set `align=center/left/right/justify` to make `\\` work without setting the width explicitly.

Comment: As starting point, I think you can refer to [How to add newline within node using TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24372/how-to-add-newline-within-node-using-tikz)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are just adding new lines in the label above the loop, then the answers were already provided in the comments.

Here is one using the `text width` option.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=3.5cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state, initial, initial where=left, accepting] (A) {A}; 
    \path[->] 
    (A) edge [loop above,text width=1cm] node {$a, b, c$ \\ $c, d, e$ \\ foo \\ bar} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another with the `align=left` option.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=3.5cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state, initial, initial where=left, accepting] (A) {A}; 
    \path[->] 
    (A) edge [loop above,align=left] node {$a, b, c$ \\ $c, d, e$ \\ foo \\ bar} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Here is with the `align=center` option.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=3.5cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state, initial, initial where=left, accepting] (A) {A}; 
    \path[->] 
    (A) edge [loop above,align=center] node {$a, b, c$ \\ $c, d, e$ \\ foo \\ bar} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

You can even use tables inside the nodes. (But this one's overdoing it already :)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=3.5cm,on grid,auto]
   \node[state, initial, initial where=left, accepting] (A) {A}; 
    \path[->] 
    (A) edge [loop above,text width=2cm] node {
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc}
    $a$,& $b$,& $c$ \\ 
    $c$,& $d$,& $e$ \\ 
    foo & & \\ 
    bar & &
    \end{tabular}
    } (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

You can see section 16, starting at 179 of the `pgf` manual for more of this.