# Start a new line in label using pgf-pie

Tags: line-breaking, labels, pgf-pie

I'm using [`pgf-pie`](http://code.google.com/p/pgf-pie/). It is not a standard package. I found it on google code. As its name, it is used to create pie chart.

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
        \pie[text=pin,style=drop shadow,rotate=240,
             explode=0.2,
             color={blue!70,cyan!70,red!70,orange!50}]{65/Amplificatori di potenza, 10/Elaborazione del segnale, 17.5/Sistemi di raffreddamento, 7.5/Alimentazione}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

I would start a new line in label. In latex the command is `\\` but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: `\\ ` does not work in TikZ nodes by default too. You need to supply the PGF key `align=center` to those labels somehow.

Comment: Maybe you be more specific?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `\\` macro doesn’t work normally in a TikZ node at all unless a `text width` or an `align`ment is set.

As you specified that the texts are in fact `text=pin` you will need to use

```
/tikz/every pin/.style={align=center},
```

The reason that the `/tikz/` tree must be prepended is that the first (optional) argument of `\pie` is forwarded to `\pgfkeys` and not `\tikzset`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
    \pie[
        /tikz/every pin/.style={align=center},
        text=pin,
        rotate=240,
        explode=0.2,
        color={blue!70,cyan!70,red!70,orange!50},
        ]
        {
            65/Amplificatori di\\potenza,
            10/Elaborazione\\del segnale,
          17.5/Sistemi di\\raffreddamento,
           7.5/Alimentazione
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As in @Qrrbrbirlbel's comment, you can't break lines by default in TikZ nodes. In this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24376/7417) it is also said, you will have to set the parameters of the node text to be able to break a line. The `\pie` command, however, won't like that, so you need to specify it globally for the whole `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9,align=center]
        \pie[text=label,style=drop shadow,rotate=240,
             explode=0.2,
             color={blue!70,cyan!70,red!70,orange!50}]{65/Amplificatori\\di potenza, 10/Elaborazione\\del segnale, 17.5/Sistemi di\\raffreddamento, 7.5/Alimentazione}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yeah it works great....