# Changing text color for charts using pgf-pie

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

Is possible to change text color inside pie chart using the pgf-pie package?

Is possible change the color of text on a single slice of the pie?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\pie[
  /tikz/every pin/.style={align=center},
  text=pin,
  rotate=240,
  explode=0.2,
  color={blue!70,cyan!70,red!70,orange!50}
] {65/Amplificatori di\\potenza, 10/Elaborazione\\del segnale,
   17.5/Sistemi di\\raffreddamento, 7.5/Alimentazione}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could try `\textcolor{enter color here}{your text here}` if the text you are talking about is in a node.

Comment: Hi Dustin unfortunately your suggestion doesn't work with this package "pgf-pie"

Comment: I can't find any documentation on this package so I don't know how you can do that.  My first comment was a guess.

Comment: While I'm not an expert, it doesn't appear to be possible at the moment without editing `pgf-pie.sty` somehow, so I would suggest placing a feature request in the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/pgf-pie/issues/list).

Comment: How can I do this by editing the file pgf-pie.sty ?

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to play with? As I discovered on [Put numbers in legend using pgf pie](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112140), `pgf-pie` is not very flexible and parts of the package probably need to be rewritten. Though you can use the `/tikz/every pin` style to change the `text` color of the labels outside of the slices (see [Start a new line in label using pgf-pie](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89345)).

Comment: in the example above, I would like that the percentages in the slices were in white

Comment: thank you for the answer Qrrbrbirlbel. You said that the use of pgf-pie is not recommend. Can you suggest an alternative better  example for create flexible pie charts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can’t really recommend `pgf-pie` due its inflexibility (and its use of the main PGFkeys path) but here is a [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) powered solution to insert a key that is tried on the node that includes the number (and only that number).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\pgfpie@slice
  {node {\scalefont{#3}\beforenumber#3\afternumber}}
  {node[/every only number node/.try] {\scalefont{#3}\beforenumber#3\afternumber}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\pie[
  /tikz/every pin/.style={align=center},
  every only number node/.style={text=white},
  text=pin,
  rotate=240,
  explode=0.2,
  color={blue!70,cyan!70,red!70,orange!50}
] {65/Amplificatori di\\potenza, 10/Elaborazione\\del segnale,17.5/Sistemi di\\raffreddamento, 7.5/Alimentazione}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer Qrrbrbirlbel. You said that the use of pgf-pie is not recommend. Can you suggest an alternative better example for create flexible pie charts?

Comment: @user21431 (To be precise, I said, that **I** don’t recommend `pgf-pie`. What others say about that I don’t know.) Well, I wouldn’t use pie charts to begin with. See [this comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5718/package-for-pie-charts#comment76778_5718)’s link (and the question) as well as [How can I produce a 'ring (or wheel) chart' like that on page 88 of the PGF manual?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17898) and [How to design a 3D donut pie chart with pgf-plot?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56254) (but please don’t use 3D, see first link).

Answer (score 2):

`/tikz/nodes={text=white, font=\bfseries, ...... },`

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\pie[
/tikz/nodes={text=white, font=\bfseries},
/tikz/every pin/.style={align=center, text=black, font=\normalfont},
text=pin,
rotate=240,
explode=0.2,
color={blue!70,cyan!70,red!70,orange!50}
] {65/Amplificatori di\\potenza, 10/Elaborazione\\del segnale,
17.5/Sistemi di\\raffreddamento, 7.5/Alimentazione}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```