# How to draw Bar & Pie Chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, bar-chart, pgf-pie

I'm want to include two graphs mentioned below in a document.

[image: Bar Chart]
[image: Pie Chart]

I'm able to draw pie charts using pgf-pie. Is there any package which is capable of generating BAR & PIE Chart both? [Also which is included in default LATEX installation] ?

Comment: Perhaps you want to try the relevant packages from the »[datatool](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool)« bundle.

Comment: Bar charts can be done with `pgfplots` (take a look at [tag:pgfplots]). Pie charts are best [not done](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128206/changing-text-color-for-charts-using-pgf-pie/130985#comment295749_130985).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For bar charts you can use pgfplots
With TikZ you can setup some macros so that you can write pie charts like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    pie chart,
    slice type={comet}{blu},
    slice type={legno}{rosso},
    slice type={coltello}{giallo},
    slice type={sedia}{viola},
    slice type={caffe}{verde},
    pie values/.style={font={\small}},
    scale=2
]

    \pie{2008}{73/comet,13/legno,7/sedia,7/coltello}
    \pie[xshift=2.2cm,values of coltello/.style={pos=1.1}]%
        {2009}{52/comet,23/legno,17/sedia,3/coltello,5/caffe}
    \pie[xshift=4.4cm,values of caffe/.style={pos=1.1}]%
        {2010}{56/comet,26/legno,9/sedia,7/coltello,2/caffe}

    \legend[shift={(0cm,-1cm)}]{{Comet (Pordenone)}/comet, {Wood and furniture (Livenza)}/legno, {Knife (Maniago)}/coltello}
    \legend[shift={(3cm,-1cm)}]{{Chair (Manzano)}/sedia, {Coffee (Trieste)}/caffe}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Obtaining

[image: Pie chart example]

The macros `\pie` and `\legend` and all the keys needed can be defined as follows:

```
\definecolor{rosso}{RGB}{220,57,18}
\definecolor{giallo}{RGB}{255,153,0}
\definecolor{blu}{RGB}{102,140,217}
\definecolor{verde}{RGB}{16,150,24}
\definecolor{viola}{RGB}{153,0,153}

\makeatletter

\tikzstyle{chart}=[
    legend label/.style={font={\scriptsize},anchor=west,align=left},
    legend box/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=5pt},
    axis/.style={black,semithick,->},
    axis label/.style={anchor=east,font={\tiny}},
]

\tikzstyle{bar chart}=[
    chart,
    bar width/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{##1/2}
        \global\let\bar@w\pgfmathresult
    },
    bar/.style={very thick, draw=white},
    bar label/.style={font={\bf\small},anchor=north},
    bar value/.style={font={\footnotesize}},
    bar width=.75,
]

\tikzstyle{pie chart}=[
    chart,
    slice/.style={line cap=round, line join=round, very thick,draw=white},
    pie title/.style={font={\bf}},
    slice type/.style 2 args={
        ##1/.style={fill=##2},
        values of ##1/.style={}
    }
]

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}


\newcommand{\pie}[3][]{
    \begin{scope}[#1]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\curA}{90}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1}
    \def\c{(0,0)}
    \node[pie title] at (90:1.3) {#2};
    \foreach \v/\s in{#3}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\deltaA}{\v/100*360}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextA}{\curA + \deltaA}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\midA}{(\curA+\nextA)/2}

        \path[slice,\s] \c
            -- +(\curA:\r)
            arc (\curA:\nextA:\r)
            -- cycle;
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{max((\deltaA * -(.5/50) + 1) , .5)}

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        \path \c -- node[pos=\d,pie values,values of \s]{$\v\%$} +(\midA:\r);
        \end{pgfonlayer}

        \global\let\curA\nextA
    }
    \end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\legend}[2][]{
    \begin{scope}[#1]
    \path
        \foreach \n/\s in {#2}
            {
                  ++(0,-10pt) node[\s,legend box] {} +(5pt,0) node[legend label] {\n}
            }
    ;
    \end{scope}
}
```

This code needs polishing and is not very general but I am sharing it as I wrote it for a document I helped typeset.
If you like it we can work out a better version.

Comment: Thanks for detail reply. Can you please suggest how to add legend in bar chart mentioned below: 

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    title=Title,
        xbar,
        xmajorgrids = true,
        bar width=6mm,
        width=12cm, height=5.5cm,
        enlarge y limits=0.2,
        xlabel={\#number},
        symbolic y coords={A,B,C,D},
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
  ]

  \addplot coordinates {(1,A) (7,B) (5,C)(2,D)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: well, you could use my `\legend` macro and put it right before the `\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: By the way this was quick and dirty code I put together some time ago, if anybody has suggestions on how to make it better, I'd be interested to hear them!

Comment: follow up question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157309/pie-chart-with-values-instead-of-percentage

Comment: I have a few items with a small percentage, and the labels are overlapping. how can I adjust this?

Comment: @user42634 see how I did that for the second pie, the value of `coltello` is `3%` and I shift the label to make it not overlapping

Comment: @bordaigorl, In this example, only the coltello label is away, in my case is 3 or more. can I paste my code here?

Comment: @user42634 I advise you to open a new question if you need more specific advice...(and in the process change your nickname to something more memorable, you might like it here =) )

Comment: I copied the legend definition, but squares in not filled. What is the possible reason?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu have you defined the `slice type`s and imported the style definitions?

Comment: Yes, of corse. I try to do my own pie diagramm once more and got desired result, but could not find reason of previous mistake. Some kind of hard-to-find one-symbol mistake, I can suppose.

Comment: I know this was a long time ago but I'm wondering if someone could help. This is a wonderful solution which I am not making use of (thanks). But I would like to make some without the values on the pie chart. How do I do that?

Comment: @JSharpee simply remove the part in the `pgfonlayer` environment. If you have more requirements write a separate question

Comment: If you want to remove 0%'s, just add `\ifdim0 pt=\v pt \else \begin{pgfonlayer}{...} \fi`

Answer (score 2):

With PSTricks

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt]{standalone}
\degrees[100]
\newcounter{counter}
\SpecialCoor
\newcommand\data[2][gray]{%
    \pswedge[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=#1,opacity=.5](0,0){4}{!\thecounter}{!\thecounter\space #2 add}%
    \uput{2}[!#2 2 div \thecounter\space add](0,0){#2\%}%
    \addtocounter{counter}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4.5,-4.5)(4.5,4.5)
    \data[red]{10}
    \data[orange]{40}
    \data[yellow]{30}
    \data[blue]{20}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To offset the angle, invoke `\setcounter{counter}=<offset>` before calling the first `\data`.

Comment: I meant `\setcounter{counter}{<offset>}`.