# Pie chart with bar chart magnification

Tags: pgf-pie

I am trying to obtain a pie chart and bar chart on the right which shows the details (magnification) of one of the slices of the pie chart (please see attached image).
I already used the code provided by Bordaigorl [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135393/how-to-draw-bar-pie-chart) to obtain the pie chart (see MWE below). Now I am struggling to get the bar chart on the right. How do I obtain this? Thanks [image]
Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\tikzstyle{chart}=[
    legend label/.style={font={\scriptsize},anchor=west,align=left},
    legend box/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=5pt},
    axis/.style={black,semithick,->},
    axis label/.style={anchor=east,font={\tiny}},
]
\tikzstyle{bar chart}=[
    chart,
    bar width/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{##1/2}
        \global\let\bar@w\pgfmathresult
    },
    bar/.style={very thick, draw=white},
    bar label/.style={font={\bf\small},anchor=north},
    bar value/.style={font={\footnotesize}},
    bar width=.75,
]

\tikzstyle{pie chart}=[
    chart,
    slice/.style={line cap=round, line join=round, very thick,draw=white},
    pie title/.style={font={}},
    slice type/.style 2 args={
        ##1/.style={fill=##2},
        values of ##1/.style={}
    }
]
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\newcommand{\pie}[3][]{
    \begin{scope}[#1]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\curA}{90}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1}
    \def\c{(0,0)}
    \node[pie title] at (90:1.3) {#2};
    \foreach \v/\s in{#3}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\deltaA}{\v/100*360}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextA}{\curA + \deltaA}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\midA}{(\curA+\nextA)/2}

        \path[slice,\s] \c
            -- +(\curA:\r)
            arc (\curA:\nextA:\r)
            -- cycle;
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{max((\deltaA * -(.5/50) + 1) , .5)}

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        \path \c -- node[pos=\d,pie values,values of \s]{$\v\%$} +(\midA:\r);
        \end{pgfonlayer}

        \global\let\curA\nextA
    }
    \end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\legend}[2][]{
    \begin{scope}[#1]
    \path
        \foreach \n/\s in {#2}
            {
                  ++(0,-10pt) node[\s,legend box] {} +(5pt,0) node[legend label] {\n}
            }
    ;
    \end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    pie chart,
    slice type={hardcoal}{blue!20},
    slice type={lignite}{red!20},
    slice type={nuclear}{gray!40},
     slice type={res}{green!20},
    slice type={ps}{red!50!yellow},
     slice type={ng}{yellow!60},
    pie values/.style={font={\small}},
    scale=2
]
\pie[xshift=1.2cm,values of ps/.style={rotate=45,font=\scriptsize},
values of ng/.style={rotate=60},values of nuclear/.style={pos=0.75},
values of hardcoal/.style={pos=0.75},align=center]{}{18.8/hardcoal,24.9/lignite,15.5/nuclear,25.7/res,5.4/ps,9.6/ng}
\legend[shift={(0cm,-1cm)}]{{Hard coal}/hardcoal, {Lignite}/lignite, {Nuclear}/nuclear}
\legend[shift={(1.25cm,-1cm)}]{{Renewables}/res, {Pumped storage, Heating oil, others}/ps,{Natural gas}/ng}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which gives me this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

A command `\WCtest` is defined of which the output depends on whether the percentage is larger than 25. This command is used in the keys `data` and `wheel data`. Here, the percentage is obtained with `\WCperc`.

The gap between the slices is obtained with the key `gap=0.02`.

The color of the slices is determined by the key `slices style=slice\WCcount`. Here the colors are defined as `slice1` and so on and `\WCcount` gives the current number of the slice.

The bar is also drawn with a `\wheelchart` by using the key `ybar={2}{5}` which gives a width of 2 and a height of 5. This bar is positioned with the key `at={(5,-2.5)}`, which defines the point below left of the bar.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\definecolor{slice1}{RGB}{100,108,33}
\definecolor{slice2}{RGB}{126,27,74}
\definecolor{slice3}{RGB}{161,109,52}
\definecolor{slice4}{RGB}{103,103,103}
\definecolor{slice5}{RGB}{130,72,9}
\definecolor{slice6}{RGB}{0,0,77}
\definecolor{bar1}{RGB}{166,166,166}
\definecolor{bar2}{RGB}{194,153,109}
\definecolor{bar3}{RGB}{1,105,178}
\definecolor{bar4}{RGB}{176,182,144}
\definecolor{bar5}{RGB}{244,244,244}
\definecolor{bar6}{RGB}{168,177,194}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\def\WCtest#1#2{%
  \pgfmathparse{\WCpercentage>25?"#1":"#2"}%
  \pgfmathresult%
}
\wheelchart[
  anchor xsep=15,
  counterclockwise,
  data=\WCtest{}{\WCvarB{} \WCperc},
  gap=0.02,
  perc precision=1,
  pie,
  slices style=slice\WCcount,
  start half=0,
  wheel data=\WCtest{\WCvarB\\\WCperc}{},
  wheel data style={white,align=center}
]{%
  25.7/Renewables,
  5.4/{Heating oil,\\Pumped storage\\and others},
  9.6/Natural gas,
  18.9/Hard coal,
  24.9/Lignite,
  15.5/Nuclear%
}
\foreach\n in {1,-1}{
  \draw ({\n*25.7*1.8}:3)--(5,{\n*2.5});
}
\wheelchart[
  at={(5,-2.5)},
  data=\WCvarB{} \qty{\WCvarA}{\percent},
  data sep=0,
  data style={anchor=west},
  slices style=bar\WCcount,
  ybar={2}{5}
]{%
  1.0/Municipal waste,
  5.6/Photovoltaic,
  3.1/Hydro,
  6.8/Biomass,
  0.2/Wind offshore,
  8.9/Wind onshore%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```