# Need to change Pie chart internal layout

Tags: tikz-pgf, pie

I have drawn the figures with following script but currently not entirely easy to read and not clearly readable if printed in black and white. Especially the pie-charts with more than three pieces. Can anyone change these charts into charts like shown in the example chart, but the colours remain the same?
I will be thankful.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{centering}
\begin{subfigure}
\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[scale=0.5]
\pie[text = legend]{
18.9/1-20 E,
29.2/21-100 E,
22.6/101-500 E,
7.5/501-1000 E,
21.7/Over 1000 E
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}
\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[scale=0.5]
\pie[text = legend]{
5.7/1 P,
43.4/2-3 P,
27.4/4-5 P,
9.4/6-7 p,
6/8-10 p,
8.5/Over 10 P
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{ (\textbf{Left}) and (\textbf{Right})}
%\end{adjustwidth}
\label{fig:SQ8-SQ9}
\end{centering}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: See [How to hatch pie charts in Tikz pgf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394135/) for setting the "slice type" pattern and colour.

Comment: Hi Ross, thanks, but  id does not work for me. Because I can not generate the colors with example. and I am not expert of pie chart things. I will be really thankful if you or some one can change the my script into required output.

Comment: Your code does not compile as it is. PLease complete it to make a full MWE, starting by `\documentclass` and ending by `\end{document}`. The you'l get help faster.