# Custom slice font style in pie chart

Tags: tikz-pgf

This question refers to the following [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135393/how-to-draw-bar-pie-chart).

See below my implementation based on the answer of bordaigorl which is really great.

```
[
pie chart,
slice type={Baunternehmen}{blu},
slice type={Vermietung}{rosso},
slice type={Sonstiges}{giallo},
slice type={Geschäftsführung}{blu},
slice type={Disposition}{rosso},
slice type={ausführender Bereich}{giallo},
slice type={Kundenbetreuung}{viola},
slice type={Materialversorgung}{verde},
pie values/.style={font={\small}},
scale=3
]

\pie[values of Sonstiges/.style={pos=1.1}]{2008}{69/Baunternehmen,28/Vermietung, 3/Sonstiges}
\pie[xshift=3cm]%
{2009}{32/Geschäftsführung/,29/Disposition, 18/ausführender Bereich, 15/Kundenbetreuung, 6/Materialversorgung}

\legend[shift={(0cm,-1cm)}]{{Baunternehmen/Baunternehmen}, {Vermietung}/Vermietung, {Sonstiges}/Sonstiges}
\legend[shift={(3cm,-1cm)}]{{Geschäftsführung}/Geschäftsführung, {Disposition}/Disposition, {ausführender Bereich}/ausführender Bereich,{Kundenbetreuung}/Kundenbetreuung,{Materialversorgung}/Materialversorgung}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am using for my document a custom font (uarial). Thus, pie title and legend values are in uarial. The slice values are standard latex font.

[image]

How do I change here to uarial font. For standard implementation of tikzpicture I am therefore using

```
nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode},
```

Same approach? But where exactly in the macro?

The macros \pie and \legend and all the keys needed are defined as follows:

```
\definecolor{rosso}{RGB}{220,57,18}
\definecolor{giallo}{RGB}{255,153,0}
\definecolor{blu}{RGB}{102,140,217}
\definecolor{verde}{RGB}{16,150,24}
\definecolor{viola}{RGB}{153,0,153}

\makeatletter

\tikzstyle{chart}=[
    legend label/.style={font={\scriptsize},anchor=west,align=left},
    legend box/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=5pt},
    axis/.style={black,semithick,->},
    axis label/.style={anchor=east,font={\tiny}},
]

\tikzstyle{bar chart}=[
    chart,
    bar width/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{##1/2}
        \global\let\bar@w\pgfmathresult
    },
    bar/.style={very thick, draw=white},
    bar label/.style={font={\bf\small},anchor=north},
    bar value/.style={font={\footnotesize}},
    bar width=.75,
]

\tikzstyle{pie chart}=[
    chart,
    slice/.style={line cap=round, line join=round, very thick,draw=white},
    pie title/.style={font={\bf}},
    slice type/.style 2 args={
        ##1/.style={fill=##2},
        values of ##1/.style={}
    }
]

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}


\newcommand{\pie}[3][]{
    \begin{scope}[#1]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\curA}{90}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1}
    \def\c{(0,0)}
    \node[pie title] at (90:1.3) {#2};
    \foreach \v/\s in{#3}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\deltaA}{\v/100*360}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextA}{\curA + \deltaA}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\midA}{(\curA+\nextA)/2}

        \path[slice,\s] \c
            -- +(\curA:\r)
            arc (\curA:\nextA:\r)
            -- cycle;
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\d}{max((\deltaA * -(.5/50) + 1) , .5)}

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        \path \c -- node[pos=\d,pie values,values of \s]{$\v\%$} +(\midA:\r);
        \end{pgfonlayer}

        \global\let\curA\nextA
    }
    \end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\legend}[2][]{
    \begin{scope}[#1]
    \path
        \foreach \n/\s in {#2}
            {
                  ++(0,-10pt) node[\s,legend box] {} +(5pt,0) node[legend label] {\n}
            }
    ;
    \end{scope}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forgot to say, welcome to the site. I added an answer, but I haven't tested it, because I honestly didn't bother making up a complete document. It is always appreciated, and in some cases entirely necessary, if you as the person asking the question makes a complete, minimal example (a [MWE, or minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228)), and not just a couple of snippets.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. Next time with a MWE. Thanks for the MWE-link.

Answer (score 1):

The `\pie` macro does

```
\path \c -- node[pos=\d,pie values,values of \s]{$\v\%$} +(\midA:\r);
```

meaning that the numbers in the slices is set in math mode. Your font setup probably doesn't change the math font, so you get standard one.

Remove the dollar signs from the node text, and the numbers will be set in text mode instead:

```
\path \c -- node[pos=\d,pie values,values of \s]{\v\%} +(\midA:\r);
```