# Tikz Pie Chart Labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pie

I am making a pie chart in Tikz. This is what it looks like so far:

[image]

The code is shown below:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pie{ 2/Demonstration of Conservatism,6/Gross Premium Valuation (GPV),  1/Loss Ratio,86/Cash Flow Testing (CFT),1/Risk Theory Techniques, 4/Other}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The picture looks ok, but I feel like the labels are pretty cramped and it looks a bit ugly. Is there a better way to put the labels so they are more spaced out?

Comment: Did you saw for example the related answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407953/16550 ? I guess that could be a duplicate for your question, right?