# Pie chart where the whole pie is just one slice

Tags: pgf-pie, pie

I have one pie chart and there is just one area, i.e. the whole pie is just one slice.

This looks like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[radius = 1,
color = {gray}, sum=auto]{1/} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

However, I want to change two things: (1) I want to remove the line within the pie chart. (2) I want to center the number, so that it is displayed exactly in the center of the pie. This would look as follows:

[image]

Any ideas how to archive that? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: It's appretierend here if you provide a full but yet minimal code (that can be compiled without further modification).

Comment: use a simple filled circle

Comment: From looking at the (thin) manual and considering the date of the last update of the manual, I do not see a solution within the package commands (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf-pie).

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135393

Comment: @Red-Cloud Thank you, I will do it like this!