# How can I make default settings for pgf-pie and have different color for text on pies and outside of pies?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

I am using `pgf-pie` for simple pie-diagrams and would like to define a color scheme that is used by default for all charts. As it seems `pgf-pie` does not offer styles or color lists by default, hence I tried to solve this by defining a `\MYpie` command that sets some standard options before applying specific settings. This works so far in my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\newcommand{\MYpie}[2][]{\pie[color={black,red,blue,orange},/tikz/draw=white,/tikz/text=white,#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[draw=white,text=white]
\MYpie{10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 10/D, 10/E, 10/F, 10/G}
\MYpie[pos={8,0}, square] {23/A, 27/B, 17/C, 13/D, 20/E}
\MYpie[pos={2,-8}, cloud] {10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 20/D, 20/E}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However there are two problems: The first is, that if I try to introduce the white text and drawing into my `\newcommand{\MYpie}`, like I do above, then I get the text white, but not the drawn lines, if I use the `%[draw=white,text=white]` instead, it works fine.

The second problem is: If my text is white, this applies to text on the pies and outside the pies, however this leads to invisible text outside the pies. So is it possible to select to different colors with pgf-pie?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135408/197451

Comment: Thanks @jsbibra, but this question basically suggests reusing the given set of commands and start from scratch. I thought it makes sense to use an existing package, so I don't have to maintain one by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key-value scheme of `pgf-pie` is ... not very flexible nor robust. Hence I patch `\pie` to let you use

- both `\pgfkeys{color=...}` or `\pie[color=...]` to specify color schemes and
- `\pie[/tikz/<key>=<value>]` to specify tikz options with scope restricted to current `\pie`.

To achieve the desired effect, in the following example I use:

- `nodes={white}` to set node text in white,
- `every label/.style={black}` to restore the label text (the text outside the pies) from white to black, since label is a subtype of node,
- `draw=white` to set the line in white.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% remove hard-coded color wheel
\xpatchcmd\pie
  {color={blue!60, cyan!60, yellow!60, orange!60, red!60,
        blue!60!cyan!60, cyan!60!yellow!60, red!60!cyan!60,
        red!60!blue!60, orange!60!cyan!60},}
  {}
  {}{\fail}

% restrict the scope of \pie options
\xpretocmd\pie{\begingroup}{}{\fail}
\xapptocmd\pie{\endgroup}{}{\fail}


\makeatletter
% set default color wheel
\def\pgfpie@color{%
  blue!60, cyan!60, yellow!60, orange!60, red!60,
  blue!60!cyan!60, cyan!60!yellow!60, red!60!cyan!60,
  red!60!blue!60, orange!60!cyan!60}
\makeatother

% set new color wheel
\pgfkeys{
  color={black,red,blue,orange}
}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  % restricted by implementation, \pie[style=...] accepts single key-value pair
  pie style/.style={thick, draw=white}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.style={black}, nodes={white}]
  \pie[style={pie style}] {10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 10/D, 10/E, 10/F, 10/G}

  % test scope
  \pie[
    color={blue!60, cyan!60, yellow!60, orange!60},
    /tikz/nodes={black},
    pos={8,0},
    square,
    style={pie style}
  ] {23/A, 27/B, 17/C, 13/D, 20/E}

  \pie[pos={2,-8}, cloud, style={pie style}] {10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 20/D, 20/E}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, thanks! For the `text=pin` option we also need to set `every pin/.style={black}`. With what you are saying about the scope in `\pie`, doesn't it make more sense to use my approach defining `\MYpie` and then put a scope around? Or would you discourage the `pgf-pie` package in general? And what way would you propose to laod different color schemes, just redefine `\pgfpie@color` every time? What I am looking for in my final solution is a corporate design aware solution which accepts 7 different presets, like `cycle list` in `pgfplots`.

Comment: @TobiBS I edited my answer to make `\pie[...]` options local and show how to locally change color scheme.

Comment: Personally I suggest to refactor the key-value scheme of `pgf-pie`.